# Can anyone identify this book about tiny spaceships

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

Outside the Moon are found tiny ships left by an alien race. volunteers get in them and press a button which cause the ship to "warp" to a distant location in the galaxy, then push another button to return. I believe they get a share of what they find. Sort of like Stargate with space ships

Comment: Could it be Frederik Pohl's  [Heechee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heechee) series?

Comment: @user14111 - My thoughts exactly.

Comment: That's close, I'm old now so its hard to remember. all I remember is that there were just these ships and they only went out and back. I remember it as a little dull and I don't remember them ever finding the alien race. I did read a lot of Pohl back in the day so this might be it

Comment: So, if there are no aliens at all, then it would be *Gateway* (the first novel in the series), but I'm having a hard time fathoming anyone finding the book dull. I just can't put that adjective into the same frame as the book which I would describe with words like "riveting", "fascinating" and "slightly disturbing".

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7346/book-from-the-late-1980s-about-an-abandoned-space-station

Answer (score 12):

This is the [Heechee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heechee) series of novels by Frederik Pohl. You're probably describing the first in the series; [Gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heechee#Gateway)

> In the main part of the series, the frontier has moved away from Venus
>   after explorers discovered an asteroid orbiting perpendicular to the
>   ecliptic plane, filled with cobalt blue tunnels, and hundreds of small
>   Heechee spaceships. The asteroid, named Gateway by the discoverers, is
>   occupied by the powerful nations of the world, who subsequently form
>   the Gateway Corporation to administer the object.
>
> By happenstance, one of the asteroid explorers enters a ship and hits
>   a button, activating the vehicle and sending him on a thirty-day
>   journey to another solar system. Upon his return, the Gateway
>   Corporation decides to allow explorers (called Prospectors) to take
>   trips on the mostly still-functioning ships. Prospectors who find
>   valuable materials or make discoveries are rewarded with substantial
>   bonuses. Ships on the asteroids come in three sizes and are defined as
>   a "one", "three", or "five" based upon the number of passengers that
>   they can (for the most part uncomfortably) carry. Not every vehicle
>   returns and there are other great hazards to the explorers.

Comment: Started to answer the same, you beat me to it. Damn you, work!

Comment: @Politank-Z - gotta be quick :-)