# Sci-fi novel or series - Explorers from Earth discover a "door" capable of reaching distant stars

Tags: story-identification

Explorers from Earth have reached the outer planets of our solar system.  On one of the planets or moons the explorers discover a "door" capable of reaching distant stars.

Folks are recruited to try the door in order to seek valuable technology or earth-type worlds.  Use of the door is risky.  Some explorers don't come back.  The civilization that created the door is considered dead.

Comment: We don't close ID questions as duplicates unless the OP has confirmed that it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Valorum So I understand. What is the correct method of proposing a duplicate though? Just for my clarification. Surely I shouldn't answer it...again?

Comment: Apart from it being a "door," everything else in the question does practically scream "Gateway."

Comment: @Valorum So I comment but not VTC...even though that auto-comments with a link?

Comment: @Paulie_D - Precisely. Post something like "*Possible dupe of [Looking for sci-fi novel I read about humanity finding alien station on orbit of Earth](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138354/looking-for-sci-fi-novel-i-read-about-humanity-finding-alien-station-on-orbit-of)"* or just the link; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138354/looking-for-sci-fi-novel-i-read-about-humanity-finding-alien-station-on-orbit-of

Comment: Ah....OK. noted. VTC rescinded.

Comment: @Paulie_D - In this case the OP has accepted that it's a duplicate and the community user has closed it. Not ideal.