# Sources where Frederik Pohl talks about health-analytic toilets

Tags: story-identification, novel

Back long ago, when I was a kid, I remember reading a passage in a Frederik Pohl novel that dealt with a smart toilet that analyzed faeces for metabolites (as we'd call them now) for health purposes.

Can anyone point me to a source where Pohl discussed this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the is mentioned in "Beyond The Blue Event Horizon" but I don't have time right now to find the relevant passages.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138354/looking-for-sci-fi-novel-i-read-about-humanity-finding-alien-station-on-orbit-of

Answer (score 9):

@bobby newmark is correct, it is in [*Beyond the Blue Event Horizon*](https://books.google.com/books?id=-al_AQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Beyond%20The%20Blue%20Event%20Horizon&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU8_PbpfvWAhUmxFQKHWjeBS8Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=toilet&f=false).

Page 166

> Also silently - it not seem so bad to talk to oneself, as long as it was not aloud - he defended himself. It was not unjustified, he thought. It was only because of the example of the bioassay unit in the toilet was always before him. For three and a half years it had been monitoring every waste product of their bodies. Of course, so it must! How else to keep tabs on their health? And if it was proper for a machine to weigh and evaluate one's excrement, why not for the excrement's author?

Comment: Yep, that's it!