# Is this the generation that will become immortal?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, immortality

In this short story, a young woman is told by her professor that medical and cybernetic technology are improving so rapidly that she may very well live forever. As the story proceeds in a series of vignettes through time, she gets her enhancements and becomes vastly more capable than before. Long after her professor has died, she remembers him fondly and creates an emulation of him for conversation. Eventually she sets the emulation aside because he is too limited, and continues her long life knowing that she will never open it again.

I read this story in an English-language anthology published probably in the 1990s or later.

Comment: "The Gentle Seduction" by Marc Stiegler https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstory-identification%5Dis%3Aa+gentle+seduction

Comment: @user14111 Completely agree.  Published in the anthology of the same name, 1990.

Comment: Wow, a five fold duplicate! That now makes me wonder what the most duplicated story id question is ...

Comment: @JohnRennie according to [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/315074/posts-that-are-the-target-of-the-most-duplicate-closures) (fetched from [this main Meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256608/398063)), it would be [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/138354/98028), the answer being *Gateway* by  Frederik Pohl. I'd have thought it'd be *Proxima Centauri* or some summon-monsters anime.

Comment: @user14111 Yes, thank you, this is the one, and I ruefully confirm that it is a duplicate question. Most likely read in [_Nanodreams_](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?23391) (1995).