# Remnants of an alien civilisation, vessels with pre-programmed destinations

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this in the 90's, but I believe that it was older; probably 80's, but possibly even as old as the 50's or 60's. I read it in English or Swedish, but I don't remember which of those. It wasn't an incredibly long story, but long enough to be a novel; probably 250-300 pages. I have no memory whatsoever of the cover.

The main plot was that the remnants of an alien civilisation had been found, and there were spacecrafts with pre-programmed destinations. These destinations had not been deciphered, and any crew taking on an assignment had no idea where they'd be going, or even if they'd return alive, but crews were still lining up to go on a mission, be it for fame or fortune.

If I remember correctly, the story is divided between Earth and/or the location where the spacecrafts had been found, and one of the spacecrafts, which had been going for quite some time, and was nearing its point of no return.

This is about all I can remember, and most annoyingly I have no memory at all of how it ended.

Comment: @DuaneDibbley Off topic, but that's a nice name you've got there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're thinking of [*Gateway*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1884), first book in the [*Heechee*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?875) series by [Frederik Pohl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederik_Pohl), which was also the answer to the questions [Looking for sci-fi novel I read about humanity finding alien station on orbit of Earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138354/looking-for-sci-fi-novel-i-read-about-humanity-finding-alien-station-on-orbit-of) and [Can anyone identify this book about tiny spaceships](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106273/can-anyone-identify-this-book-about-tiny-spaceships) and [Book from the late 1980's about an abandoned space station](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7346/book-from-the-late-1980s-about-an-abandoned-space-station).

From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heechee) description:

> In the main part of the series, the frontier has moved away from Venus after explorers discovered an asteroid orbiting perpendicular to the ecliptic plane, filled with cobalt blue tunnels, and hundreds of small Heechee spaceships. The asteroid, named *Gateway* by the discoverers, is occupied by the powerful nations of the world, who subsequently form the Gateway Corporation to administer the object.
>
> By happenstance, one of the asteroid explorers enters a ship and hits a button, activating the vehicle and sending him on a thirty-day journey to another solar system. Upon his return, the Gateway Corporation decides to allow explorers (called Prospectors) to take trips on the mostly still-functioning ships. Prospectors who find valuable materials or make discoveries are rewarded with substantial bonuses. Ships on the asteroids come in three sizes and are defined as a "one", "three", or "five" based upon the number of passengers that they can (for the most part uncomfortably) carry. Not every vehicle returns and there are other great hazards to the explorers.
>
> The novel *Gateway* was serialized in *Galaxy* beginning November 1976, with illustrations by Vincent DiFate, and was published as a book by St. Martin's Press in April 1977. It won four major awards as the year's best English-language speculative fiction or science fiction novel. Translations into French, German, Dutch, and Italian were all published during 1978 and 1979.
>
> The *Gateway* novel focuses on the exploits of one of those explorers, Robinette Broadhead. Broadhead hits the jackpot by becoming the first person to return from a black hole's event horizon. In the sequel, Broadhead uses the money to fund further discoveries involving Heechee technology, locating a Heechee food factory that is capable of turning raw carbon, hydrogen, oxygen and nitrogen (CHON) from comets into edible food for an overpopulated Earth.